# One record from one table to show up on all records on another table

Tags: sql, etl, data-analysis

I have two tables. Table A and B. Table A would have data like:

```
    +---+---+---+
    | a | b | c |
    +---+---+---+
    | 2 | 1 | 8 |
    | 3 | 6 | 7 |
    | 4 | 5 | 9 |
    +---+---+---+
```

And table B as:

```
    +----+----+
    | e  | f  |
    +----+----+
    | 11 | 14 |
    +----+----+
```

I want to create a SQL query that would provide me an output where I keep all the records from table A and only the one record from table B, but the values from that one record in each column from table B would show up in all the records in table A. The result of the data set would look kike this:

```
    +---+---+---+----+----+
    | a | b | c | e  | f  |
    +---+---+---+----+----+
    | 2 | 1 | 8 | 11 | 14 |
    | 3 | 6 | 7 | 11 | 14 |
    | 4 | 5 | 9 | 11 | 14 |
    +---+---+---+----+----+
```

I am not sure how SQL handles appending records like this on table result. I would assume that there is a way to call out those fields from table B and do some kind of union to table A? If there is another question that has the answer then please flag this question as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coudl try using a cross join

```
select a, b, c, d, f
from A
cross join B
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are by definition unordered and there are no row identifiers.  You can create a row identifier using `row_number()` and then use that for a `join`:

```
select a.a, a.b, a.c, b.e, b.f
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (order by e) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

This assumes that the first column in each table defines the ordering, as in your example data.